# Identifying component of cockatiel mix

Tags: feeding, cockatiels

[image]

Our cockatiel pays more interest to this seed than anything else, but we don't know what it actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are oats, the company all living things sells [oat spray](http://www.petsmart.com/bird/food-and-treats/treats/all-living-things-oat-sprays-bird-treats-4151.html) if you wanted to add more.

Comment: You can also get a treat mix called "oats and groats"... It's a good treat supplement commonly used for stressed parakeets. I'd just make sure youre adding a variety of things to his diet, especially if he's picking through and eating these. They contain beta-glucans, which are antinutritional factors that naturally reduces nutrition availability to your birds digestion tract.

Comment: Based in the UK i'm having difficulty tracking down both oat sprays and the like.